# QGIS Eclipse + PyDev tool autocomplete

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I set up my QGIS plugin development environment in Eclipse with PyDev using [the instructions](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html).

I've got the autocomplete working for qgis and qt4 objects:
[image]

but I can't figure out how to get the code complete working for my form controls:

[image]

Notice how I only get autocomplete for functions I've already used.

I realize this is tricky since the control is defined in the UI file. I just wanted to check if anyone else had solved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible, in the sense that UI is build (python coded) dynamically (not at editing time). The way to have form autocomplete during editing is to build the UI with pyuic4 compiler (as was done before the uic compilation), than import the compiled module and use it in place of FORM_CLASS.
I use this way when I strongly need completion during editing of during remote debug, in most of cases it's not necessary, and generally I return to the compiled on the fly FORM_CLASS at deploy phase.